# Texture of ImageButton is not displayed on some devices when used TextureAtlas

Tags: libgdx

I am using libGDX 1.0 and not sure if it is a bug or not.

My ImageButton is displayed correctly on a LG OPtimus and HTC Desire using TextureAtlas. However, on a Galaxy Tab2 the it becomes completely back, but it is still clickable.

If I load its texture from the AssetsManger, everything works fine on any device.

Here is the relevant part of the code:

```
            stage = new Stage(new StretchViewport(fontCamera.viewportWidth,fontCamera.viewportHeight));

            ImageButtonStyle styleButtonPlay = new ImageButtonStyle();

            //this works
            //textureButtonPlay = new TextureRegion(game.manager.get("data/ui/play.png",Texture.class));
            //styleButtonPlay.imageUp =  new TextureRegionDrawable(textureButtonPlay);

            //this don't on Samsung Tab2
            atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/shot/atlas.pack");
            styleButtonPlay.imageUp =  new TextureRegionDrawable(atlas.findRegion("ui/play"));

            buttonPlay = new ImageButton(styleButtonPlay);
            buttonPlay.addListener(

                    new ClickListener() {
                        public boolean touchDown(InputEvent event, float x, float y, int pointer, int button)
                        {
                            startGame();
                            return true;
                        }

                    });

            buttonPlay.setSize(80, 60);
            buttonPlay.setPosition(camera.viewportWidth/2 - buttonPlay.getWidth()/2,5);
            stage.addActor(buttonPlay);
```

I now am concerned about packing all my sprites onto single imaged.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The problem has been resolved by creating a texturepack.png with the size smaller than 4096x4096. 
For some reason it was ok only on some devices and no similar problem has been noticed on the desktop.

Hope this help someone...

Answer (score 0):

see your code here:

```
        atlas = new TextureAtlas("data/shot/atlas.pack");
        style.imageUp =  new TextureRegionDrawable(atlas.findRegion("ui/play"));
        ^^^^^

        buttonPlay = new ImageButton(styleButtonPlay);
                                     ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

it looks like you assign the wrong style to your imageButton, try putting the drawable into the correct button style ("styleButtonPlay" instead "style"):

```
        styleButtonPlay.imageUp =  new TextureRegionDrawable(atlas.findRegion("ui/play"));
```

Comment: Thanks @donfuxx. I forgot to change "style" to "styleButtonPlay" in my question. As it was commented out before, the re-factor did not change the variable's name. Also, it does explain why it works on 2 real devices and not on the Galaxy Tab2. Sorry for the silly when I wrote the question.